# Format structured XML international mailing addresses into text

Tags: xml, api

I'm looking for a turnkey solution to format structured international mailing addresses into flat text.

Below, an example of input data I have:

```
<address>
       <lastname>Smith</lastname>
       <firstname>John</firstname>
       <street>Woodland</street>
       <streetNr>5</streetNr>
       <city>Beaconsfield</city>
       <dept>QC</dept>
       <zip>H9W 4V8</zip>
       <countryIso>CA</countryIso>
</address>
```

As output, I would like the following lines of text :

```
Smith John
5 Woodland
Beaconsfield QC H9W 4V8
Québec
CANADA
```

I have addresses of lots of countries and since each country has a different way to address mails, I would like to find an existing API/service to do that.

I'm also interested in ways to implement such solution based on UPU standards for example (http://www.upu.int/en/activities/addressing/postal-addressing-systems-in-member-countries.html).

Comment: What have you tried? Note that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Will there be xml elements for Québec and CANADA?